# VBA If/Else Statement to Copy and Paste Data Based on Count of Column

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy and paste data from the same column (A) in multiple sheets into a single column of a data in a final sheet.

The code I have used so far works perfectly if there is more than one row of data beneath the header row.

The sheet is formatted to include a table beneath the data and if there is only one row of data on the sheet the existing code will copy data from cell A2 to the first cell in the table with data (essentially performing ctrl+shift+down).

I need an if statement to count a range of data (could be A2:A3) and if the count is greater than 1 it would copy all the data down the column to first empty row. Then paste it to the first empty row in Column A of another sheet. Else copy cell A2 and then paste it to the first empty row in column A of another sheet.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
If Range("A2:A3").Count > 1 Then
    Range("A2",Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Copy Destination:=Sheets("QA").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)  
ElseIf Range("A2:A3").Count = 1 Then
    Range("A2").Copy  Destination:=Sheets("QA").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
End If
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - just so you know, your code (not a picture of the code) needs to be in the question otherwise you will not find many people willing to help.

Comment: Thanks Sam. Updated.

Comment: Is this an actual Excel table?

Answer (score 1):

This will work. You really just need to check if `A3` has data.

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim source as Range
    If Len(.Range("A3")) then 
       Set source = .Range(.Range("A2"),.Range("A2").End(xlDown))
    Else
       Set source = .Range("A2")
    End If

End With

Dim dest as Range
Set dest = Worksheets("QA").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

dest.Resize(source.Rows.Count,1).Value = source.Value
```